# Datasets dedicated for SIEM systems

Tags: detection, siem, anomaly-detection

I am looking for data sets published by researchers or freelancers which can be used for the purpose of SIEM testing and evaluations. The goal is to test the classification (and later correlation) for this system.

Some researchers used [Packet Clearing House SKAION2006 IARPA Dataset](https://www.impactcybertrust.org/dataset_view?idDataset=183), I have queried a request to use the dataset but unfortunately my request was denied (only US-based researchers, with some countries included, can use it).

- Do you have any publicly available datasets for SIEM systems?
- A friend recommended me the KDD99 dataset, but this one was designed to evaluate IDS/IPS systems in nature. I believe I can't use it for this reason, what do you think?

Bests,

Answer (score 3):

Here is some links that may help you:

https://vizsec.org/data/

http://www.fukuda-lab.org/mawilab/data.html

https://mcfp.felk.cvut.cz/publicDatasets/

On the other hand, consider datasets from 1999 is not going to be very useful unless you are testing the stability of your system, but for detection/classification I don't think will help from my point of view

Comment: Thank you very much. I do agree on what you said about the KDD99, I am not going to use it for the same reason, also I don't think it will do much for a SIEM system since KDD99 is designed for IDS/IPS syetems.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a curated list https://www.secrepo.com/

It contains data sets for various security attacks, threat feeds, machine learning, network and more.

Hope this helps.